# Projeto com Spring não salva no Mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Criei um projeto com o Spring boot e não consigo salvar dados no Mysql. Não é exibida nenhuma mensagem de erro. O Spring cria as tabelas, mas não insere os dados.

Classe User

```
package com.projeto.principal.entity;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;



@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() {

    }
    public User(String nome, String email) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }   
}
```

Interface UserRepository

```
package repository;

        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        import com.projeto.principal.entity.User;
        public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

        }
```

Classe de Inicialização de Dados

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
    import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.projeto.principal.entity.User;

    import repository.UserRepository;

    @Component
    public class DataInicializr implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {
            //Sempre vai rodar no inicio da aplicacao
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail("maria@gmail.com");
            user.setNome("Maria");      
            userRepository.save(user);              
        }
    }
```

Comment: Chegou a debugar p/ verificar se realmente esta instrução está sendo executada?

Comment: Filipe, fiz o degug e ele nao esta entrando nessa instrução

Comment: Então, encontrasse o problema. :) Agora, verifique as anotações e veja o motivo pelo qual não tá invocando este método.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer apenas rodar um código simples, pode usar a interface `CommandLineRunner` na sua classe main. O próprio spring injetar uma implementação para sua classe UserRepository.

**OBS:** Toda vez que iniciar o servidor, seu banco será populado, se você quer trabalhar com migração de dados sugiro usar [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) ou [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);

  }

  @Bean
  CommandLineRunner runner(UserRepository ur) {
    return args -> {
       ur.save(entity) \\ codigo que voce quiser executar após inicializacao
    };
  }


}
```